# Why don't we consider centrifugal force on a mass placed on earth?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, centrifugal-force

Let us say a block of mass is placed on the surface of earth. Then while drawing the forces on that body, we say:

1. Force $F = mg$ acting towards the center of Earth.
2. Normal reaction $N$ offered by the surface of Earth.

If no other forces are acting, we say $F=N$. But what about the centrifugal force $m\omega^2R$ . Why don't we ever bring that into picture? What am I missing?

Comment: See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8074/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/299723/2451

Comment: ""Why don't we ever bring that into picture? What am I missing?"" You missed to read about the many cases where "that was brought into picture".

Comment: @Georg : Thanks for pointing that out. Now, I do want to read about those cases. Could you point me to some of those cases/examples/problems?

Comment: Read any medium physics textbook on "gravity dependence on latitude". Any clockmaker knows why a pendulum at equator has to be somewhat shorter than at say, 50th parallel.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because it's effect is smaller than the variation in $g$ due to earth's bulge (caused by the same centrifugal force) or the local geology - when you use $9.8m/s^2$ that's just an approximation.

The effect of the bulge and centrifugal force mean that $g$ at the equator is about 0.5% lower than $g$ at the poles

edit: velocity at equator   $40,000 km / 24 h = 1666.7 km/h = 0.463 km/s$

'centrifugal g' =  $(0.463 km/s)^2 )/ 6375 km = 0.03 m/s^2$  or 0.3% of 'g'

Comment: How is it smaller? $\omega$ is angular velocity of earth which is large and `R` is radius of earth which is also large.

Comment: The *magnitude* of the force is smaller than the variation in 'g' - the centrifugal force is about 0.1 - 0.2% of 'g'

Comment: Interestingly doing the numbers it's larger than I guessed

Comment: ω is small - it's 2pi/(24*60*60) rad/s.  It might help to think of it in F=mv^2/R terms, remember R is big

Comment: Dear @Martin, you're wrong that the variation of $g$ due to the centrifugal force is smaller than the variation of $g$ because of the bulge, which is also caused by the same centrifugal force. Up to a factor of at most 2, they're the same. See http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8074/

Comment: @Lubos - yes, I worked it out. But it's still small enough that if you are using 9.8 for'g' you don't need to care

Comment: Yes, sure, unless you of course buy gold for a million of dollars and using a different weight, they steal $3000 from you. ;-)

Comment: @Luboš - or my new diet that just moves people form Oslo to Mexico city

Comment: If you buy gold, you bring a calibration weight with you and use a balance. That removes the effect of $g$ from your purchase...

Comment: @Floris - if you know a gold seller that will accept my calibration weight I can make money without 'g' ;-)

Comment: @MartinBeckett presumably if you want to buy enough gold that it matters, you would want to confirm the calibration of the supplier's scale - and if your measurements disagree, walk away. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/138296/26969)

Answer (score 8):

I think that all the right physics is contained in Martin Beckett's answer and the comments on it, but I'd like to restate it in a way that may bring out what I think the key point is.

In practice, when we do experiments in a lab near Earth's surface, we use a value of $g$ that's been determined empirically at that location. For instance, we might determine it by dropping something in vacuum and measuring its acceleration with respect to our lab. That value of $g$ already includes the centrifugal contribution, so we don't need to (indeed we must not!) include it separately.

We often tell introductory physics students that $g$ is the "acceleration due to gravity," but strictly speaking we're telling a small lie when we do this: $g$ is really the acceleration due to gravity *and inertial forces*.

Of course, that lie is only a lie in the context of Newtonian mechanics: when we get to general relativity the distinction between gravity and inertial forces goes away anyway! The acceleration of a falling object in general relativity is most naturally thought of as being *all* inertial force: the falling object is moving along a geodesic, and the reason we see it as accelerating is that our lab is not in an inertial reference frame.