# Net acceleration felt by a body on Earth

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, centrifugal-force

For any body on earth will the only acceleration it has be gravity or should we take into consideration even centrifugal force due to rotation?

Is there any precise formula to determine the net acceleration?

Comment: Maybe you read up a little more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation#Astronomy and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force_(fictitious)#Earth

Comment: Your thinking is correct, you will need to account for the centrifrugal force due to rotation. In fact, this centrifrugal force IS the reason why one weighs less at the equator than at the poles.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9751/2451 and links therein.