# How much water did I actually drink?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature, water, volume

Water expands at temperatures over $5^\circ\mathrm C$ strictly monotonic.
If you now drink $1~\mathrm{L}$ water ($5^\circ\mathrm C$) which will expand in your body on $37^\circ\mathrm C$, did you actually drink $1 ~\mathrm{L}$ water or $37^\circ\mathrm C$-volume?

Comment: If you put a red ball into a box with no lights inside, does the red ball turn black?  It's a matter of perspective.

Answer (score 4):

$1$ litre of water will remain almost $1$ litre as long as it is in the liquid state, no matter what the temperature is.

The following formula gives you an order of magnitude estimate of the expansion:

$$\Delta V=V_0\ \Delta T \ \beta$$

where $\beta$ is the coefficient of thermal expansion and $V_0$ is the initial volume.

For water, $\beta \approx 10^{-4}\; \mathrm K^{-1}$.

Therefore, if $1$ litre of liquid water is heated by $40^\circ\mathrm C$, the volume will only change by $\approx 1 $ millilitre.

However, you might have notices that when you heat up a closed plastic bottle filled with water, it seems to expand a lot more and may even make the bottle explode if heated for long enough. This is due to part of the water turning into vapour, which occupies a much greater volume $\approx 1000$ times more.  The higher the temperature, the more evaporation you have.

Answer (score 1):

Volume is not a meaningful measure of quantity, for the reason you hint at in your question.

You can say how many moles (or grams) of water you drank - more useful if you want to know about the impact on your body chemistry.

This is related to [my answer about scales measuring in grams rather than Newtons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/138296/26969). Can you see how?