# Rotation of earth and effect on $g$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, earth, centrifugal-force

How do we calculate the change in the acceleration due to gravity (consider earth as a uniform sphere) with a change in the rotation speed of earth along its axis? 
How do we build up a mathematical relationship between these two phenomenon?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Why don't we consider centrifugal force on a mass placed on earth?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9751/)