# Is the normal force equal to weight if we take the rotation of Earth into account?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

In my physics class we were doing problems such that we set $N$ (normal force) $= mg$. I understand that by Newton's Third Law, if I exert a force on the ground, then the ground will exert an equal and opposite force on me. However, the part that I am slightly confused about is that when the Earth rotates, and thus I rotate too, I am accelerating with the centripetal force towards the center of the earth (assuming I am at the equator). How am I doing this if the normal force equals $mg$? If the normal force doesn't equal mg then why isn't the ground exerting an equal and opposite force?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/299723/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9751/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't we consider centrifugal force on a mass placed on earth?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9751/)

Answer (score 6):

You are right to question this. The normal force is equal to the weight is when the acceleration in the direction of these forces is $0$. More explicitly,
$$\sum F=N-mg=ma=0$$
$$N=mg$$
(I'm sure you could contrive examples where there are more forces in this direction so that $a\neq0$ but $N=mg$, but I won't do that here).

There are many examples where $N\neq mg$. For example, in an elevator that starts moving up, the normal force exceeds your weight in order for you to accelerate upwards.

In your example of the earth, the acceleration is equal to $\frac{v^2}{r}$ where $v$ is your linear velocity and $r$ is the radius of the Earth. Therefore$^*$,
$$N=mg-\frac{mv^2}{r}\neq mg$$
You also specifically ask why this is the case in this scenario. The physical reason is because your instantaneous velocity is tangent to the Earth, thus you have some "pull" away from the Earth (due to your inertia), causing a reduced normal force. (You could also move to a rotating frame and attribute this to a centrifugal force).

In the case of a box resting on an incline at angle $\theta$, the normal force and the weight are not aligned, and so it turns out that 
$$N=mg\cos\theta\neq mg$$

So as you can see, we really can only take these forces to be equal when they are in the same direction and there is no acceleration. (Once again, you could probably contrive some examples to make this not the case, but I am talking more generally here)

---

$^*$ The value of $g$ I use here is from the approximation of a spherical Earth at rest, so that $g=\frac{GM}{R^2}$ where $G$ is the gravitational constant, $M$ is the mass of the Earth, and $R$ is the radius of the Earth. If you considered $g$ to be the measured value of acceleration near Earth's surface, then there centrifugal effect would already be in effect in this measurement. In any case the point still stands that the normal force is not equal to the force of gravity between you and the Earth.

Comment: Would you also be able to answer this part for me. If the normal force the ground exerts upon me is not equal to mg which I exert on the ground how does this correlate with Newton's third law (equal and opposite pairs)?

Comment: @98CB1, mg and the normal force are two separate forces acting on you, they are not third law pairs.  The normal force on you is equal to the force that you exert downward on the earth.  mg is equal the the gravitational force that you pull upward on the earth.

Comment: Why would the force I exert on the ground not be equal to my weight (mg)? @BowlOfRed

Comment: @98CB1, if they were equal, then the net force on you would be zero and you would not be accelerating.  But as you said, your rotational motion around the earth requires acceleration.  That circular motion/radial acceleration is due to the difference between the forces.

Comment: I guess what I am asking is what is the force that I exert on the earth? If the normal force is equal to the force I exert on the earth but the force I exert on the earth is not equal to mg, then what is it?

Comment: @98CB1 Just to clarify, when you say "force I exert on the Earth", do you mean the force you exert on the ground while you stand on it, or the gravitational force between you and the whole Earth?

Comment: @98CB1 It seems like you mean the ground. Then the normal force and the force you exert on the ground are equal and opposite to each other. My answer tells you what $N$, and hence what the force the ground pushes on you, is on the rotating earth. However if you are talking about the entire gravitational force between you and the entire Earth, then you pull on the Earth with a force of $mg$ just as it pulls on you with a force of $mg$.

Comment: It rather depends on what "g" actually is. When taking g as "acceleration of free fall" (in German "Fallbeschleunigung") that should already have the "centrifugal force" due to the earth's rotation baked in, so N=mg would hold.

Comment: @piet Yes that is true. I decided not to discuss this point, since it is mainly irrelevant for the discussion. The main point is that $N\neq w$ (although barely) where I am assuming $w$ is your weight on a stationary Earth. In other words, $g=\frac{GM}{R^2}$ Thank you for clarifying though.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to finalize the conclusion from @AaronStevens's great answer. In the truer expression for normal force (on flat ground) that he arrives at,

$$N=mg-\frac{mv^2}{r}=m\left(g-\frac{v^2}{r}\right)\quad ,$$

Earth's rotation adds the term $\frac{v^2}{r}$ so it deviates from the expected $N=mg$. How much is the influence of $\frac{v^2}{r}$?

Earth's radius is around $r=6400\;\mathrm{km}$. In one day, which is $t=24\,\mathrm{hr}=86400\,\mathrm s$, we move through the entire circumference of Earth, which is $d=40200\,\mathrm{km}$. That gives us a constant speed of around $v=d/t=465\,\mathrm{m/s}$. *I am aware that I have used rough numbers here, from the top of my head, mainly fitting from the Equator. You can try to redo the calculations with more accurate values.*

If we plug in $r$ and $v$, we get something like:

$$\frac{v^2}{r}=0.0338\,\mathrm{m/s^2}$$

Compare this with $g=9.80\,\mathrm{m/s^2}$. The contribution of Earth's spin to the effective gravitational acceleration $(g-\frac{v^2}{r})$ is thus only something like 0.3 %. You can try to calculate a normal force for an object with and without this influence and see if there is a significant difference within significant figures.

Comment: Does the fact that the earth orbits around the sun also influence this? and also maybe the fact that the sun orbits the center of the milky way?

Comment: @IvoBeckers This can be calculated in the same simple way, if you look up the length and radius of the orbit. I wouldn't bet my money on them having anywhere near a significant influence. We might be far further down in the decimal digits that they affect.

Comment: @IvoBeckers Why not consider the pull from everything in the universe? You have to stop somewhere.

Comment: @IvoBeckers You're almost in freefall around the Sun, so you're almost weightless with respect to it. I say "almost" because you aren't exactly located at the barycenter of the Earth-Moon system, so there are minor tidal corrections to consider.

Comment: @Steeven surely the calculation is not the same. We are in stable orbit around the sun, so the gravitational force *and* the centrifugal force (both neglected in the simple calculation) are nominally in equilibrium and cancel out. Our usual state on Earth is not a geostationary orbit which is why we have a tendency to accelerate towards the ground which is equilibrated by the normal force.

Comment: Your top-of-head numbers are quite good. I get about 0.03377 m/s^2 using the figures from Google's calculator, vs. ~ 0.03382 with yours. Not even worth talking about the difference :)

Comment: @Will You are also in stable orbit around the Earth. That doesn't mean that the "centrifugal force" on you at this spinning globe cancels out the gravitational force in you. If you move in a circular path around anything, which you do around the Sun, then there is a net acceleration present and not a force balance.

Comment: @Will *A sidenote for the record, to avoid confusion:* The "centrifugal force" is in fact not a force, but just a (miss-worded) term for the effect of being "swung" outwards in the orbit. And this outwards-swinging effect is already included in the expression, namely as the $v^2/r$ term.

Comment: @hobbs Thanks, but I was just adding that disclaimer since I know that there are many more small factors that play into the numbers. They depend on where you are located, also in altitude, and should maybe be calculate to more significant figures. And with more significant figures, the value of $g$ might already include the effect of Earth's spin, depending on how you measured it (with a simple Newton-meter or from the general gravitational force expression). I chose to save some time and do it more roughly in this answer...

Comment: @Steeven standing on the surface of a planet that happens to be rotating is **not** an orbit by any reasonable definition. Of course the centrifugal force in this system doesn't cancel out the gravitational force. That is ***why*** a normal force appears before you start accelerating through the ground beneath you. The difference when it comes to the sun's orbit is that a body that *is* in orbit around the earth is subject to exactly the same forces from the sun and accelerates exactly the same way. So it has nothing to do with determining the normal force from the ground.

Comment: @Will Aha, okay, I see your point. There is no normal force in the Sun-Earth situation. True. But the general method - although with the right forces used - is the same. And you can calculate the contribution to $g$ from any such orbit in a way similar to what is shown.

Comment: @Steeven yes, but the comment you were responding to didn't ask about the general method for solving two-body equilibrium in a rotating system; it was asking whether the orbit around the sun affected *this* problem of the normal force on a free body at rest on earth - which it doesn't.

Comment: @Steeven as for centrifugal force, I never said it was "real" but working in a rotating reference frame and considering the equilibrium of all forces in it acting on a body, fictitious and otherwise, is an extremely conventional approach in physics and I thought I should be able to refer to it here without further explanation!

Comment: @Will Hmm, okay, we might understand that comment differently, but I see what you mean.

Comment: @Will Regarding the "centrifugal force", if it is to be included as a "balancing force" in the Sun-Earth case then why shouldn't it be assumed in the person-Earth case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85851/discussion-between-will-and-steeven).

Answer (score 1):

@Aaron has nicely explained using mathematics.

Let me brief it out qualitatively and also give a slightly different way of looking at it.

- following the line of thought in @Aaron's answer, the normal force does not equal mass multiplied by g.
- so the difference between gravitational pull and the normal force will provide centripetal acceleration that keeps you going round in circle with the earth.
- however, in most cases the effective value of g is used instead of using g as acceleration due to gravity. In the effective g, the centrifugal force (as seen from our frame of reference) and other factors such as height and latitude variations are also accounted for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a diagram of an ideal spherical Earth radius $R$, mass $M$ rotating at an angular speed $\omega$ with an object mass $m$ in contact with the surface of the Earth.

[image]

The object on the Earth is subject to two forces: 
gravitational attraction $\frac{GMm}{R^2}=mg$ where $g$ is the gravitational field strength and a reaction due to the Earth $N$.

The net force on the object produces the centripetal acceleration of the object.

At the poles there is no centripetal acceleration so $mg -N_{\rm pole} = m 0 \Rightarrow N_{\rm pole} = mg$ the equation that you quoted in your first sentence.

At the Equator the equation of motion is $mg - N_{\rm equator} = mR\omega^2$ so the normal reaction $N_{\rm equator}$ is smaller than the gravitational attraction $mg$.

At other points on the Earth the reaction $N$ is smaller than the gravitational attraction $mg$ but not by as much as at the equator but you will note that on a spherical Earth that reaction is no longer normal to the Earth's surface.

A better approximation to the shape of the Earth is that it is an oblate spheroid (like a squashed sphere) as shown greatly exaggerated below.

[image]

With the Earth being that shape the reaction force on the mass is normal to the surface and in general a plumb line does not point towards the centre of the Earth.
Now another correction has to be made as the value of the gravitational field strength $g$ varies from being a maximum at the poles and a minimum at the Equator.

Answer (score 0):

That is a reasonable question.  If the earth were isolated, not rotating and perfectly spherical, then $g$ would be the same everywhere on the surface.  But it's not any of those things.  You are right that centripetal acceleration reduces the measured weight of an object.  You can calculate that easily: the centripetal acceleration effectively reduces the weight of a mass (on the equator) $m$ by an amount equal to $m$ x the angular rotation speed x the radius of the Earth.  This is further complicated by the fact that the Earth is a slightly oblate spheroid, and therefore $g$ varies slightly with latitude.  These factors are discussed in detail in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth).