# Circular motion of an object on the floor of equator

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Object A is located on the floor at the equator.
Is that the magnitude of the normal force on A equal to its weight?

How to obtain an expression for normal reaction in terms of $m,g,r$ and $\omega$?

Comment: Duplicate [Is the normal force equal to weight if we take the rotation of Earth into account?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/441245/is-the-normal-force-equal-to-weight-if-we-take-the-rotation-of-earth-into-accoun/441298#441298)

Answer (score 0):

The normal force from the floor (or the reading on a scale) would be N where: mg - N = mR$ω^2$.  The, R, and,  ω, are the radius and angular velocity of the earth.