# rotation of earth and changes in its diameter

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

could calculated the changes of the Earth's diameter cause the rotation?? I have seen 2 other posts about it but I couldn't understand their calculation and they were a little confusing and couldn't conclude anything special with calculation.

Comment: Your post is a bit incomprehensive. Can you clarify your question, post the links you are referring to and explain what is unclear?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8074/2451 and links therein.