# Why isn't $g$ larger on the equator?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, earth, planets, centripetal-force

I understand that at the equator, you will have maximum centripetal force acting on you, whereas if you're standing directly on the pole you will have none.
But because centripetal is a resultant force, why isn't the value of $g$ GREATER on the equator because you'd need a greater force to 'pull' you inwards to force you to travel in circular motion?

Comment: The pull of gravity on Earth's surface depends on various factors: outward centrifugal force is greatest at Equator, this counteracts against the Earth's gravity and as a result the downward acceleration due to gravity at Equator is a teeny weeny bit lesser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Earth's gravity stronger at the poles?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141856/)

Comment: Hi Hattie. It's always worth [a quick search of this site](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=gravity+equator) as you'd be surprised how many questions have been asked before. In this case the link I've suggested precisely answers your question.