# Why is gravity high at poles but lower inside the surface of Earth, as compared to $g$ on surface?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, earth, centrifugal-force

My high-school physics teacher recently displayed some formulae stating at when we dig deeper the gravity pull is lower but at poles (the flattened part) it is appreciably higher.
Now, if we consider the Earth a perfect sphere, the poles will be as if someone dug it out, so shouldn't the pull at the poles be lower rather than higher?
Please be specific and thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Earth's gravity stronger at the poles?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141856/)

Comment: See also [this post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18446/) (and any of the "linked" questions) for gravity underground.

Comment: Part of the problem is we cannot consider the Earth to be a perfect sphere, because it isn't, and that is at least part of the reason for why gravity is stronger at the poles.