# Calculating Distance between Prime Meridian and WGS84 location?

Tags: geometry, geodesics

I'm trying to calculate the distance between the WGS84 meridian at 51°28′40.1″N 0°0′5.3″W and the actual prime meridian at 51°28′40.1″N 0°0′0″W in feet.  [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_meridian_(Greenwich)) claims the two points are 5.3'' from each other.  My calculation below results in 334 feet and this differs from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_meridian_(Greenwich))'s answer of 336.21 feet.  I looked at Google maps and used the measure feature, after which I measured 190 feet between both coordinates and this is pictured.

Does anyone know how to correctly calculate this and why the differences between Google, Wiki and my calculation?

$1^\circ = 60′ = 60\,\text{nm} = 69\,\text{mi}$

$1′ = 60″ = 1\,\text{nm} = 1.15\,\text{mi}$

$1″ = 60″′ = 1/60\,\text{nm} = 101.2\,\text{feet}$

$5.3'' \cdot 101.2\,\text{feet} * cos(51.47°) = 334\,\text{feet}$

[image]

Comment: Hi notaorb. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: @Qmechanic how is this a homework question?  I'm asking how the prime meridian location is calculated on different platforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used the simple rule
$$1' = 1\ \text{nm}.$$
This rule is correct for distances in north-south direction.
But for distances in west-east direction it is not so simple.

You need to consider the fact that neighboring meridians
don't have a constant distance.
(Just look at a globe to understand this.)
Instead, the meridians get closer and closer to each other,
when walking away from the equator towards the north or south pole.
At the equator you have
$$1' = 1\ \text{nm}.$$
But going away from the equator the correct rule
for west-east distances becomes
$$1' = \cos(\phi)\cdot 1\ \text{nm}$$
where $\phi$ is the geographical latitude.
In your case you have $\phi=51.47°$,
and hence $\cos(\phi)=0.6228$.

Comment: WGS84 uses an ellipsoid, but over that small distance, the difference between the geodesic length on a sphere vs the ellipsoid is about half a metre. According to https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/scripts/geod-calc.html The distance is 102.282 m ~= 336'6.85" (that calculation ignores altitude).

Comment: @PM2Ring Well, ok. For the sake of simplicity, I have treated the Earth as a sphere instead of an ellipsoid.

Comment: Sorry but what does $\text{nm}$ stand for here? Obviously not *nanometer*...

Comment: Perhaps the ellipsoid geometry needs to be taken into account?  It seems 192' (Google), 290' (above), and 336' (Wiki) have large differences.

Comment: @Gert nautical mile

Comment: Ah. Thank you, friend.

Comment: @Notaorb Google Earth uses the EGM96 geoid (or maybe 2008), but that differs from WGS84 by 147 feet at Greenwich.

Comment: @JEB, I get 334' using poster's advice, so that is off by 142'.  I looked up EGM96 and read Wiki's Geoid entry, where the Geoid is the shape of the Earth's surface if it were covered by water under Earth's gravity.  How would this result in -142' for Google?  Is Greenwich part of an oblate ellipsoid that such that the radius to center is less, resulting in shorter length and Google's number?

Comment: I'm talking about the _height_ about the ellipsoid vs the _elevation_ above MSL. Most maps (& modern GPS) report elevation, but this calculation requires height. My answer is 100% the correct answer, I know this because google (and DOD, and the CIA, NRO, etc..) got their map from NGA (formerly NIMA, formerly DMA), who got the map from NASA, who got the map from JPL, who got it from section 334 who executed SRTM shuttle mission, and I got a NASA achievement award for calibrating the whole damn thing, and I used the software I wrote for that on this problem. QED.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is 335.573739 feet.

The easiest way to do this is convert lat, lon, height to ECEF and compute the cartesian distance. I just posted the formula here ([Actual astronomic latitude (direction of gravity) does not match calculations taking into account centrifugal force of earth](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/659032/actual-astronomic-latitude-direction-of-gravity-does-not-match-calculations-ta/659194#659194)).

Of course, that is "as the neutrino flies" and doesn't follow the surface of the Earth. At this distance, the difference is micron tiny.

A more accurate method is to place a locally tangent sphere on one of the points and then project the other onto the sphere, you then get an arc length between them. It gives the same answer to within 1 micron. For instance, if you place the locally tangent sphere at the 1st point, and put the second point on the sphere, you find that it sits at a bearing of 89.9994209 (slightly north of due East), and at a distance of 102.281619 meters, and 0.001028 meters north of great circle pointing due east, with an elevation of 0.9 nanometers (sphere's aren't ellipsoids, but if you use locally Cartesian coordinates, the elevation is -0.8 millimeters, so the sphere is a much better approximation).

An iterative solutions called Vincenty's formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae) also works.

The 336.5' number is wrong...probably uses the spherical solution.

btw: I used a height for Greenwich of 84.7 meters.