# If Earth is oblate why don't oceans flow to the Poles?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, rotational-dynamics, earth, equilibrium, centrifugal-force

The Poles are  ~21 km downhill from the equator in a spherical coordinate system.

So why doesn't water pool there?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Why is the Earth so fat?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8074/2451) and links therein.

Comment: Thanks. That's useful stuff. I wonder whether it answers this question though.

Comment: There's some relevant info at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geopotential & the other articles linked on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the Earth's rotation it has a centrifugal force that causes the equatorial bulge. The water in the oceans rotate with the Earth so at the equator the water has more centrifugal force acting on it than it does closer to the poles.

Comment: So would the Equator become a desert if the Earth stopped spinning ?

Comment: @cumfy If the Earth stopped spinning then gravity would pull it into a more spherical shape, so it would lose its polar flattening. That process wouldn't be instantaneous, but neither would any process that stops Earth spinning, assuming that you don't want to rip the crust off. ;)

Comment: @cumfy With no rotation sea levels would change over most of Earth and the whole Earth would eventually become more spherical, altering the shape of most land mases.