# Change in $g$ effective due to rotation

Tags: newtonian-gravity, acceleration, planets, centrifugal-force

$g$ effective at any latitude changes due to rotation of earth. Does it also change due to rotation when the body is at height or at depth or does it change only at the surface?

Edit: I am referring to variation in acceleration due to axial rotation of earth which changes with the latitude. Does it depend on the height or depth of the body also?

Comment: Are you referring to centripetal acceleration? That’s going to depend on radius, so it’ll change as you move further away from and closer in to the body

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8074/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acceleration due to gravity at a certain latitude is given by :
$$g_{new}=g-R\omega^{2}cos\theta$$
where R is radius of earth(that is valid if you are on surface) , $\omega$ is angular velocity and $\theta$ is latitude of earth

It is certain that "R" changes with height or depth because its the distance from center of earth and hence the $g_{new}$ must change